# difference between `<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />` and `rel="nofollow"`

Tags: seo, meta-tags, nofollow, meta-robots

Is the meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />`

The same as `rel="nofollow"` in a link (apart from the fact the the meta tag would be page wide rather than on a per link basis)

Or does the meta tag version refer to wether robots should crawl the links on the page, rather than if they pass 'link juice' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The same as rel="nofollow" in a link (apart from the fact the the meta tag would be page wide rather than on a per link basis)

Yes, same as `rel="nofollow"`, except the `nofollow` in the meta tag applies to *all* the links on the page.

> Or does the meta tag version refer to wether robots should crawl the links on the page, rather than if they pass 'link juice'?

Well, that is what the `rel="nofollow"` attribute on the link does as well. It tells the bots not to follow that link. ie. Don't crawl it. A by-product of that is that it also won't pass "link juice".

From [Google Search Console Help "Use rel="nofollow" for specific links"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en):

> Originally, the `nofollow` attribute appeared in the page-level meta tag, and instructed search engines not to follow (i.e., crawl) any outgoing links on the page.
>
> Before `nofollow` was used on individual links, preventing robots from following individual links on a page required a great deal of effort (for example, redirecting the link to a URL blocked in robots.txt). That's why the `nofollow` attribute value of the `rel` attribute was created. This gives webmasters **more granular control**: instead of telling search engines and bots not to follow any links on the page, it lets you easily instruct robots not to crawl a specific link.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same if you follow HTML5’s definitions:

- HTML5’s definition of the [link type `nofollow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-nofollow) is:

  > The `nofollow` keyword indicates that the link is not endorsed by the original author or publisher of the page, or that the link to the referenced document was included primarily because of a commercial relationship between people affiliated with the two pages.
- HTML5 refers to [MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) for the registration of metadata names, which says about the `nofollow` value for the `robots` name:

  > […] "nofollow" works as the link rel value with the same name.

  (This was [added by Aleksandersen on 2007‎-06-30](https://wiki.whatwg.org/index.php?title=MetaExtensions&oldid=2365).)

(Note that Google Search [doesn’t seem to](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) follow HTML5’s definition, but Google Search also makes no difference between `nofollow` as metadata name and as link type.)

However, in HTML 4.01, the [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.2) for the `nofollow` value in a `meta`-`robots` element is different (bold emphasis mine):

> The `META` element allows HTML authors to tell visiting robots whether a document may be indexed, or **used to harvest more links**. […]
>
> In the following example a robot should neither index this document, nor **analyze it for links**.

This seems to be in line with the definition on robotstxt.org, where it says [about `meta`-`robots`](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html):

> Don't confuse this NOFOLLOW with the [rel="nofollow" link attribute](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/relnofollow.html).

And in the linked FAQ entry it says:

> From that description it sounds like it only affects the ranking, and the Google robot may still follow the links and index them. If so, it is different from the [robots meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) NOFOLLOW semantics.

(FWIW, the mentioned description doesn’t seem to make this difference anymore.)

And the Microformats wiki says about `rel="nofollow"` under [open issues](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-nofollow#open_issues):

> **Name.** nofollow is a bad name.
>
> - overloading. does not mean the same as robots exclusion standards (robots.txt, meta robots) nofollow.